# Conditional Formatting with openpyxl based on text

Tags: python, python-2.7, openpyxl

I have a  spreadsheet that I am generating with openpyxl that contains a number of system checks. Based on the rules; the words Pass, Fail or Informational are inserted into Column E in my spreadsheet. I would like to use Openpyxl to conditionally format the fill of the spreadsheet based on the value of Pass or Fail. Something like Green for Pass and Red for Fail.

My current code for openpyxl is:

```
wb = Workbook()
ws = wb.active
ws.freeze_panes = ws.cell('A3') 
ws.title = 'Best Practice Report for XXX'
ws['A1'] = 'Best Practice Report for XXX %s' % curdate
ws['A2'] = 'IP Address/FQDN'
ws['B2'] = 'BP Number'
ws['C2'] = 'Title'
ws['D2'] = 'Priority'
ws['E2'] = 'Status'
ws['F2'] = 'Description'
a1 = ws['A1']
a1.font = Font(size=20)
redFill = PatternFill(start_color='FFEE1111', end_color='FFEE1111', fill_type='solid')

ws.conditional_formatting.add('E4:E1000', FormatRule(text=['Fail'], stopIfTrue=True, fill=redFill))     
wb.save('bp--TESTresults.xlsx')
```

My issue is with the conditional formatting rule, I cannot find any good examples for conditional formatting based on the text in a cell.

***Update***
Thanks to Charlie Clarks response I got this working. Created two rules as follows.

```
ws.conditional_formatting.add('E4:E1000', FormulaRule(formula=['NOT(ISERROR(SEARCH("Pass",E4)))'], stopIfTrue=True, fill=greenFill))    
ws.conditional_formatting.add('E4:E1000', FormulaRule(formula=['NOT(ISERROR(SEARCH("Fail",E4)))'], stopIfTrue=True, fill=redFill))
```

Comment: I'd be tempted to use introspection on an existing file. Starting with openpyxl 2.2 the rules are exposed as Excel sees them. I agree that the docs could be a lot better but I've personally very little experience with conditional formatting.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I just whipped up a file and did some introspection. It has values in A2:A5 I think this should help you along:

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook
wb = load_workbook("Issues/cf.xlsx")
ws = wb.active
ws.conditional_formatting.cf_rules
{'A2:A5': [<openpyxl.formatting.rule.Rule object at 0x108e6dfd0>]}
rule = _['A2:A5']
rule = rule[0]
rule.type
'containsText'
rule.formula
['NOT(ISERROR(SEARCH("fail",A2)))']
rule.stopIfTrue
None
rule.operator
'containsText'
```

Comment: Thank you for this information, it has helped me to figure out to to implement the containsBlanks and notContainsBlanks functionality

Comment: @Charlie It seems the code has changed and `cf_rules` does not exist anymore in `ws.conditional_formatting`. You now have `ws.conditional_formatting._cf_rules` that returns an `OrderedDict` though.

Answer (score 0):

The solution `'NOT(ISERROR(SEARCH("fail",A2)))'` works for checking if a cell contains a certain value.

If you are looking for a perfect match, the easiest way so far is to use formula and equality (because operator `cellIs` for `Rule` raises an error in Excel):

```py
from openpyxl.formatting.rule import FormulaRule

...

ws.conditional_formatting.add(
    "E4:E1000",
    FormulaRule(formula=['E4="Pass"'], stopIfTrue=True, fill=greenFill),
)
ws.conditional_formatting.add(
    "E4:E1000",
    FormulaRule(formula=['E4="Fail"'], stopIfTrue=True, fill=redFill),
)
```

or using a dictionary, you could do:

```py
text_2_color = {"Pass": greenFill, "Fail": redFill}
for text, color in text_2_color.items():
    ws.conditional_formatting.add(
        "E4:E1000",
        FormulaRule(formula=[f'E4="{text}"'], stopIfTrue=True, fill=color),
    )
```